# Float AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

Hi i want to create float activity for that i know that i can set this style to my activity.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

But i need to extend my activity to AppCompatActivity to set apply styles in older version of android.
so what can i do for that?
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the setup I use:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.MinWidth">
    <item name="windowFixedWidthMajor">@dimen/dialog_fixed_width_major</item>
    <item name="windowFixedWidthMinor">@dimen/dialog_fixed_width_minor</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> <!-- No dialog title bar. -->

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```